# Looping through each xml node

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I hope this isn't a duplicate question. I've spent quite a bit of time looking around for a working solution but I'm having no luck. What I'm trying to do is loop through each xml Node and get a specific node out. To achieve this I'm using Ruby, Nikogiri and xpath.

So I have and simple xml file that looks like this sitemap.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask1/</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask2/</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask3/</loc>
</url>
```

So I'm trying to extract each . This is my code:

```
siteMap = 'sitemap.xml'
sm = File.open(siteMap)
docSM = Nokogiri::XML(sm)

siteMapLinks = docSM.xpath("/url/loc").inner_text
print siteMapLinks.to_s + "\n"
```

The output >

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask1/
```

So as you can see it does not output all nodes/tags. I have tried putting the code in a for loop but all it does is repeat the same node. Any idea how to get my desired output:

Desired output >

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask1/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask2/
http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask3/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was close but misses out on a few petty details. Nokogiri parses your XML until the first top level tag is closed, so if you want it to parse all the URLs you will need some encapsulating tag as in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urls>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask1/</loc>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask2/</loc>
  </url>
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask3/</loc>
  </url>
</urls>
```

Now you can query your document with

```
docSM.xpath("//url/loc").each do |node|
  puts node.inner_text
end
```

If you do

```
docSM.xpath("//url/loc").inner_text
```

as you suggested you will get a single string with all the text concatenated and no separator in between.

Comment: Actually you can parse it as a Nokogiri `DocumentFragment` without needing to insert the root tags.

Answer (score 2):

Your file is not a valid XML document because [it contains more than one root node](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element). If you `inspect` the contents of your `docSM` variable you should be able to see that Nokogiri has only parsed the first `<url>` because it's the first root node.

You need to contain all of the `<url>`s in a higher-level node to create a valid document. I.e

```
<urls>
  <url>...</url>
  <url>...</url>
</urls>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your XML isn't valid. You can test that by looking at the `errors` method of your document:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<url>
  <loc>http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask1/</loc>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask2/</loc>
</url>
EOT

doc.errors # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document>]
```